# how do I reference a specific object in array that has changed with angular $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

I am attempting to calculate the new total whenever price or qty change. I don't understand how to get a reference to the specific object that has changed.

```
$scope.parts = [{description: null, price: 0, qty: 0, subtotal: null}]
$scope.partsTotal = 0

$scope.$watch('parts', =>
  $scope.partsTotal += $scope.parts.price * $scope.parts.qty
  $scope.parts.subtotal = $scope.parts.price * $scope.parts.qty
, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new watch on each object in the array, and then use watch with the first parameter being a function returning the object (I'm using underscorejs to iterate over the array):

UPDATE: you might lost the reference using _.each(), so if that doesn't work try a for loop...

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.parts.length; i++) { var part = $scope.parts[i]; ... }

_.each($scope.parts, function(part) {

$scope.$watch(
  function() { return part; },
  function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal.price !== oldVal.price || newVal.qty !== oldVal.qty) {

      //run the update

    }
  }
);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object literal inside of an array literal.

You would have to access the "subtotal" property in your example like this:

```
$scope.parts[0].subtotal
```

$watch(es) get the new values and the old values passed in when they fire. I would try to reproduce with your example but I can't bring myself to write it with Coffee. You can grab the values from the arguments going in, or you can access the object directly like you are there (which might be easier considering you're using a deep watch).

Comment: would you consider writing it in javascript?

Comment: I'd be happy to. If you could put together a jsfiddle/plunkr of something changing, I can show you how to grab changes happening. If you just want me to show you a generic example of a $watch, then I would tell you that the documentation does a fine job of that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope